# REST client using both Simple XML and Gson libraries: Use common POJOs or adapter pattern?

Tags: java, adapter, strategy-pattern

In my java app (specifically, Android app), I make a REST call (GET). The response could be either XML or JSON. I use a Strategy Pattern which decides what parser to employ based on the Content Type of the response.

If the response is XML, I use Simple library to parse the response into my POJOs, and if the response is JSON, I use Gson library.

Now my question: Is there any benefit in having a single POJO which containing both Simple and Gson annotations? Or, is it better to separate out the 2 POJOs and then have an Adapter (or maybe Wrapper) to "convert" to a generic POJO? In other words, what are the pros and cons of the following approaches?

### Approach 1:

```
class PojoCommon {

    @SimpleXmlAnnotations
    @GsonAnnotations
    private int age;

    @SimpleXmlAnnotations
    @GsonAnnotations
    private String name;

    //Constructors, Getters and Setters ...
}
```

### Approach 2:

```
class Pojo{

    private int age;
    private String name;
}

class PojoXml{
    @SimpleXmlAnnotations
    private int age;

    @SimpleXmlAnnotations
    private String name;

    public Pojo toGenericPojo(){
        return new Pojo(this.age, this.name);
    }
}

class PojoJson{

    @GsonAnnotations
    private int age;

    @GsonAnnotations
    private String name;

    public Pojo toGenericPojo(){
        return new Pojo(this.age, this.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Approach 1 is better IMHO for software maintenance

Comment: I thought the same, but problem is the way you set up the annotations and POJOs might change depending on the library. Tomorrow, if I decide to dump Simple and go for, say, JAXB instead; there might be changes in the way the POJOs are set up. Also, I might add a third content type in addition to XML and JSON. All these led me to believe that approach 2 is actually more maintainable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Approach1 is better in term of maintenance but you already have answered your question as in long term with any proposed changes it can make things complex.

My Suggestion is to go for second one create POJO for each individual type and use a wrapper/adapter approach for the conversion

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Umesh. I'm wondering about the performance implications of the repeated wrapping (and un-wrapping) calls. My objects are not really heavyweight (up to two dozen Strings and native data types)...

Comment: @techie.curious though you can always prefer the first one but thing is you can't sure in advance how much more type your application will support in future and you have already mentioned that concern so using a single POJO means mixing all things together which is in my opinion not a good way to go.